# Combine arbitrary shaped tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to combine two variable length tensors.

Since they don't match in shape I can't use tf.concat or tf.stack.

So I thought I'd flatten one and then append it to each element of the other - but I don't see how to do that.

For example,

```
a = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]
flat_b = [5, 6]

combine(a, flat_b) would be [ [ [1,5,6], [2,5,6] ],
                              [ [3,5,6], [4,5,6] ] ]
```

Is there a method like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tf.map_fn` with `tf.concat`, Example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([ [1,2], [3,4] ])
flat_b = [5, 6]
flat_a = tf.reshape(a, (tf.reduce_prod(a.shape).numpy(), ))[:, tf.newaxis]
print(flat_a)
c = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: tf.concat([t, flat_b], axis=0), elems=flat_a)
c = tf.reshape(c, (-1, a.shape[1], c.shape[1]))
print(c)
```

Outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[1 5 6]
  [2 5 6]]

 [[3 5 6]
  [4 5 6]]], shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: i get InvalidArgumentError: sizes input must be 1-D, not [] [Op:Reshape], maybe it depends on tf version or soemthing

Comment: @ What TF version you using? I test using TF V2.3

Comment: tensorflow 2.0.0

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky where did you get the error?

Comment: flat_a = tf.reshape(a, tf.reduce_prod(a.shape))[:, tf.newaxis]        .... InvalidArgumentError: sizes input must be 1-D, not [] [Op:Reshape]

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky I updated the answer, now it should solve your problem

Comment: i upvoted, justa as an aside, i think it might be possible to combine with python lists first and then just create a single tf object in one single line... seems a bit complex... but this is a highly unusual operation.. nice solutoin

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky , glad to help, because you ask using `tensorflow` to do so, so the solution code is not looking very neat, if you are deal with data (or inputs to model) then I suggest you using `numpy` to do it, that gonna be much easy and neat

Comment: FYI, you can reduce your number of operations by using `tf.stack`. Also I would advise using `tf.expand_dims` and flattening with `tf.reshape(x, [-1])`. I implemented these changes in another answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat simpler version of the previous answer. Rather than reshaping several times, I prefer to use `tf.expand_dims` and `tf.stack`. The latter adds a dimension so that's one less call to `tf.reshape`, which can be confusing.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = [5, 6]

flat_a = tf.reshape(a, [-1]) 

c = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.concat([[x], b], axis=0), flat_a)
c = tf.stack(tf.split(c, num_or_size_splits=len(a)), axis=0)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[1, 5, 6],
        [2, 5, 6]],
       [[3, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]]])>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could go through element-wise. In list form you would do something like out[i][j] = [a[i][j]]+flat_b starting from out being the same shape as a. This gets to the form you wanted. I'm not sure if there is this sort of element-wise concatenation in the tensorflow library.